# jQuery slick slider with multiple rows not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I would like to have two rows of images for a basic slider. I am using Slick Slider, but it doesnt seem to be working even though I am following their instructions. What am I doing wrong?

This is the link to Slick Slider JS website:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

My HTML:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
  <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
  <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
  <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
  <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
  <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.carousel').slick({
          dots: true,
          slidesPerRow: 3,
          rows: 2,
          responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
              slidesPerRow: 2,
              rows: 1,
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 640,
            settings: {
              slidesPerRow: 1,
              rows: 1,
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    });
```

I have created a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/zts1nok8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution for this, incase anyone faces similar issue in the future:

```
.item img {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.carousel').slick({
          dots: true,
          slidesPerRow: 1,
          rows: 2,
          responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1024,   
            settings: {
              slidesPerRow: 1,
              rows: 1,
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 640,
            settings: {
              slidesPerRow: 1,
              rows: 1,
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c5ak1hxz/1/

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve the effect you want by wrapping your images and using some simple CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carouselItem">
    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="carouselItem">
    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/482618/hubfs/demo-logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carouselItem{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.carouselItem img{
  display:inline-block;

}
```

If you do this you will probably want to remove all that stuff about rows in the slick config. That appears to be bugged to be honest. You could possibly send an issue to the developer.

For responsivity, you could possibly do something with CSS media queries and hiding/showing the right images. This would work best if you are just using the same image three times per slide.

See JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Chipmo/0u8g9aLt/2/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using slick slider version 1.8.1 and using **slick.min.js** file then replace the file with **slick.js** file only because slick.min.js has some broken code.
This works for me

Answer (score 1):

It's actually working but you have to set it correctly.

Please change the

```
slidesPerRow: 1
```

and try again.

Comment: okay thanks, but i want three slides per row to show side by side, similar to the carousel in this page:

https://www.optimizely.com/resources/testing-toolkit/

Answer (score 1):

please try changing

```
slidesPerRow:3
```

to

```
slidesToShow:3
```

and add

```
slidesToScroll:3
```